# Haskell API for accessing a SQLite database

Tags: haskell, json, api, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, and I'm trying to make a web API for it. I've been writing it in Haskell, and using `scotty` as the server. I templated out the website from [the Scotty Starter Kit](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty-starter), and then started making the API there. I'm a complete Haskell beginner (this is my very first project), so I'm sure there's a lot here I'm not doing right. There are probably lots of opportunities for refactoring. [This file, as well as the rest of the project, can also be found here](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/84fca6681789b7c15d329cf3385894ce200156aa/src/Main.hs). Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.Map (fromList)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Data.Aeson (toJSON)
import Controllers.Home (home, docs, login)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger (logStdoutDev)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Static        (addBase, noDots,
                                             staticPolicy, (>->))
import System.Environment (getEnv)
import Web.Scotty

-- Needed for type declarations
import Data.Convertible.Base

db :: String -> String
db environment = case environment of
  "prod" -> "/mnt/vol/pg-text-7.db" 
  "dev" -> "/home/jon/Code/gitenberg-scrape/pg-text-7.db"
  _ -> error "Environment must be one of 'prod' (production) or 'dev' (development)."

port :: String -> Int
port environment = case environment of
  "prod" -> 80
  "dev" -> 8000
  _ -> error "Environment must be one of 'prod' (production) or 'dev' (development)."

getByAuthor :: (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible String SqlValue, IConnection conn) => conn -> String -> IO [[(String, SqlValue)]]
getByAuthor conn person = do
  stmt <- prepare conn "select * from meta where author like ?"
  _ <- execute stmt [toSql person]
  fetchAllRowsAL stmt

getIDsByAuthor :: (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible String SqlValue, IConnection conn) => conn -> String -> IO [[SqlValue]]
getIDsByAuthor conn person = do
  stmt <- prepare conn "select id from meta where author like ?"
  _ <- execute stmt [toSql person]
  fetchAllRows stmt

getFullText :: IConnection conn => conn -> [SqlValue] -> IO [[(String, SqlValue)]]
getFullText conn ids = do
  let query = "select id, text from text where id in (" ++ intersperse ',' ('?' <$ ids) ++ ")"
  stmt <- prepare conn query
  _ <- execute stmt ids
  fetchAllRowsAL stmt

getByID :: (Convertible String SqlValue, IConnection conn) => conn -> String -> IO (Maybe [(String, SqlValue)])
getByID conn bookID = do
  stmt <- prepare conn "select * from meta where id = ?"
  _ <- execute stmt [toSql bookID]
  fetchRowAL stmt

sqlToText :: Maybe [(String, SqlValue)] -> Maybe [(String, String)]
sqlToText maybeSqlPairList = case maybeSqlPairList of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just sqlPairList -> Just $ map getVal sqlPairList where
    getVal (a, val) = case val of SqlNull -> (a, "NULL")
                                  _ -> (a, fromSql val :: String)

filterOutFields :: Maybe [(String, String)] -> Maybe [(String, String)]
filterOutFields maybeSqlPairList = case maybeSqlPairList of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just sqlPairList -> Just $ filter allowed sqlPairList where
    allowed (key, _) = take 3 key `notElem` ["am_", "gr_"]

-- textToJson :: Maybe [(String, String)] -> String
textToJson maybePairList = case maybePairList of
  Nothing -> ""
  Just pairList -> do
    let myMap = fromList pairList
    toJSON myMap

--processSql :: Maybe [(String, SqlValue)] -> Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value
processSql sqlPairList = textToJson $ filterOutFields $ sqlToText sqlPairList

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting server..."
  env <- getEnv "ENV"
  let portNumber = port env
      dbPath = db env
  conn <- connectSqlite3 dbPath
  scotty portNumber $ do
    get "/api/hello/:name" $ do
      name <- param "name"
      text ("hello " <> name <> "!")
    get "/api/id/:id" $ do
      bookID <- param "id"
      sql <- lift $ getByID conn (bookID::String)
      json $ processSql sql
    get "/api/id/:id/fulltext" $ do
      bookID <- param "id"
      sql <- lift $ getFullText conn [toSql (bookID::String)]
      json $ map (processSql . Just) sql
    get "/api/author/:author" $ do
      author <- param "author"
      sql <- lift $ getByAuthor conn (author::String)
      json $ map (processSql . Just) sql
    get "/api/author/:author/fulltext" $ do
      author <- param "author"
      ids <- lift $ getIDsByAuthor conn (author::String)
      sql <- lift $ getFullText conn (map head ids)
      json $ map (processSql . Just) sql
    middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static/images") -- for favicon.ico
    middleware logStdoutDev
    home >> docs >> login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on the first detaill I've noticed, mainly the `String` argument in both `db` and `port`. Only `"prod"` or `"dev"` are valid values. However, `String` has many more values that are valid `String`s, e.g. `"Example"` and `"Hello, World"`. But those aren't valid database environments.

Therefore, we should use a type to make sure that we don't need to check whether we have a valid environment at hand:

```
data DBEnvironment = DBProduction
                   | DBDevelopment
                   deriving (Eq, Show)
-- feel free to shorten those names
```

Now `db` and `port` can be written without us having to worry aobut wrong environment strings:

```
db :: DBEnvironment -> String
db environment = case environment of
  DBProduction  -> "/mnt/vol/pg-text-7.db" 
  DBDevelopment -> "/home/jon/Code/gitenberg-scrape/pg-text-7.db"

port :: String -> Int
port environment = case environment of
  DBProduction  -> 80
  DBDevelopment -> 8000
```

If we enable `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, GHC will even tell us when we forgot to handle a DB environment that we might add later:

```
data DBEnvironment = DBProduction
                   | DBDevelopment
                   | DBStaging  -- added later, -fwarn-incomplete-patterns warns us
                   deriving (Eq, Show)
```

We only need a single additional function to use our `DBEnvironment`:

```
parseEnvironment :: String -> Maybe DBEnvironment
parseEnvironment s = case s of
  "prod" -> Just DBProduction  
  "dev"  -> Just DBDevelopment 
  _      -> Nothing
```

Our `main` only changes slightly:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting server..."
  Just env <- parseEnvironment <$> getEnv "ENV"
  let portNumber = port env
      dbPath = db env
  ...
```

You could add a proper error message, but that's left as an exercise. Note that *if* we have an `env` at that point, we know that it's also a valid one. That's a big win compared to the previous situation where we had to check whether the `String` was valid in every function.

---

Other than that, there are some instances where you use `:: String` where they're not necessary, e.g. `getByID conn (bookID::String)`. `getByID` takes a `String` as second argument, so while the type signature `:: String` is not wrong, it's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

`processSql` can be assembled from library functions.

To reduce code duplication, turn the parts that differ into the parameters of a function you implement once. The things you happen to be doing here can be written in terms of a few modules.

Try to inline everything that's used only once.

```
wrap name suffix adapter wrapped = get ("/api/" ++ name ++ "/:" ++ name ++ suffix) $ do
  p <- param name
  sql <- lift (wrapped p)
  json $ (\processSql -> adapter processSql sql)
    $ toJson . fmap (fromMaybe "Null" . fromSql) . fromList
    . filter (\(key, _) -> take 3 key `notElem` ["am_", "gr_"])

(<&>) = flip (<$>)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting server..."
  (db, port) <- getEnv "ENV" <&> \case
    "prod" -> ("/mnt/vol/pg-text-7.db", 80)
    "dev" -> ("/home/jon/Code/gitenberg-scrape/pg-text-7.db", 8000)
    _ -> error "Environment must be one of 'prod' (production) or 'dev' (development)."
  run <- connectSqlite3 db <&> \conn query fetch args -> do
    stmt <- prepare conn $ "select " ++ query
    execute stmt args
    fetch stmt
  let run1 query fetch arg = run query fetch [toSql (arg :: String)]
  scotty port $ do
    get "/api/hello/:name" $ do
      name <- param "name"
      text ("hello " <> name <> "!")
    wrap "id"     ""   (maybe "") $ run1 "* from meta where id = ?" fetchRowAL
    wrap "id"     "/fulltext" map $ run1 "id, text from text where id = ?" fetchAllRowsAL
    wrap "author" ""          map $ run1 "* from meta where author like ?" fetchAllRowsAL
    wrap "author" "/fulltext" map $ run1 "id from meta where author like ?" fetchAllRows
      >=> \ids -> run
        ("id, text from text where id in (" ++ intersperse ',' ('?' <$ ids) ++ ")")
        fetchAllRowsAL (map head ids)
    middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static/images") -- for favicon.ico
    middleware logStdoutDev
    home >> docs >> login
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. Although I still need to learn what things like `>=>` are doing.